Let f be such Boolean function that 0,1 ∈ [{ f }]. Prove that f is the Sheffer function.
Let f be such Boolean function that 0,1 ∈ [{ f }]. Prove that f is the Sheffer function.
Here's what [] means:
The closure [Φ] of the set Φ is the set of all Boolean functions implemented by formulas over Φ.
So, basically we need to prove that we can not implement both constants simultaneously by a single boolean function if it is not a Sheffer stroke.
I don't see any other way except for brute force - check all boolean functions of two variables and show that only two of them can represent both constants - Sheffer stroke and Pierce arrow.
Have I guessed correctly or there is another way to solve this problem?

Your question is not very clearly phrased. But taking $f$ to be the complement of the Sheffer stroke (NOR) would surely also satisfy the assumptions, so the problem doesn't seem to be correctly stated.

As I understand, "Sheffer function" means that closure of f is complete. That's not only about Sheffer stroke or Pierce arrow but about every such function.
